# How do I align all vertical lines to be the same distance as each other from a horizontal line?

Tags: html, css

I am making a "timeline" component and I am wondering how I can make the vertical lines all line up with each other, displaced by the same amount above/below the horizontal line.

The vertical lines may have different number of lines of text above them, so my current solution of using `align-self:center` isn't working here.

```css
.container {
    width: 30vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.timeline-box {
    width: 90%;
    position: relative;
}

.timeline-strip {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 200px;
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: scroll; 
}

.timeline-box:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0px;
}

.point {
    margin: 0 7px;
    align-self:center;
}

.timeline-point {
    width: 90px;
    position: relative;
}
.timeline-point:before {
    content: '';
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    border-left: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="timeline-box">
      <div class="timeline-strip">

        <div class="point">
          <div>Text 1</div>
          <div>Text 2</div>
          <div class="timeline-point"></div>
          <div class="date">2020-10-05</div>
        </div>

        <div class="point">
          <div class="timeline-point"></div>
          <div class="date">2020-10-06</div>
        </div>

        <div class="point">
          <div>Text 1</div>
          <div class="timeline-point"></div>
          <div class="date">2020-10-07</div>
        </div>

        <div class="point">
          <div>Text 1</div>
          <div>Text 2</div>
          <div class="timeline-point"></div>
          <div class="date">2020-10-08</div>
        </div>

        <div class="point">
          <div class="timeline-point"></div>
          <div class="date">2020-10-09</div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want like this?

```css
.container {
    width: 30vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.timeline-box {
    width: 90%;
    position: relative;
}

.timeline-strip {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 200px;
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: scroll; 
}

.timeline-box:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0px;
}

.point {
    position: relative;
    height: 150px;
    bottom: 25px;
    margin: 0 7px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
}

.timeline-point {
    width: 90px;
    position: relative;
}
.timeline-point:before {
    content: '';
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    border-left: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="timeline-box">
    <div class="timeline-strip">

      <div class="point">
        <div class="events">
          <div>Text 1</div>
          <div>Text 2</div>
          <div>Text 1</div>
          <div>Text 2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-point"></div>
        <div class="date">2020-10-05</div>
      </div>

      <div class="point">
        <div class="events"></div>
        <div class="timeline-point"></div>
        <div class="date">2020-10-06</div>
      </div>

      <div class="point">
        <div class="events">
          <div>Text 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-point"></div>
        <div class="date">2020-10-07</div>
      </div>

      <div class="point">
        <div class="events">
          <div>Text 1</div>
          <div>Text 2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-point"></div>
        <div class="date">2020-10-08</div>
      </div>

      <div class="point">
        <div class="events"></div>
        <div class="timeline-point"></div>
        <div class="date">2020-10-09</div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```